# Toggling dynamic table columns with checkboxes in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning Angular, and I am building a permissions table for a webapp. There are multiple tools within the app and different users have different permissions. I want checkboxes to control what users are being shown in the table.

Here is a jsbin to show you a demo: http://jsbin.com/epuziq/2/edit

I can get the checkboxes to toggle the headers, but I'm struggling on how to hide the columns of table data associated with the header. I can change the JSON to fit any solution.

Is there a way to do this with Angular? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I know this is old but wrote this directive that solves it. 
 it do all alone.

https://github.com/cesardmoro/tableColumnToggler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the code which populates  in your table to the below and it works fine!

```
<tr ng-init="headers = permissions.headers"
    ng-repeat="tabledata in permissions.tool1">
    <td>{{ tabledata.permission  }}</td>
    <td ng-show="headers[0].selected">{{ tabledata.userone }}</td>
    <td ng-show="headers[1].selected">{{ tabledata.usertwo }}</td>
    <td ng-show="headers[2].selected">{{ tabledata.userthree }}</td>
    <td ng-show="headers[3].selected">{{ tabledata.userfour }}</td>
    <td ng-show="headers[4].selected">{{ tabledata.userfive }}</td>
</tr>
```

Also, in your use case it makes more sense in making the association of users with permission levels and not the other way round & you could have saved yourself from such a mess. For example, the following collection would have been a piece of cake for a use case as yours.

```
"users" : [
    {
         "title": "User One",
         "filter": "userone",
         "selected": true,
         "permission 1" : yes,
         "permission 2" : yes,
         "permission 3" : no
    }
     ... and so on
```

Comment: maybe it better to use $index instead of array hardcoding indexes

Comment: $index will have same value for all the elements here, even I wanted to use it but hard luck..

Comment: Awesome, that seems to work perfectly. Is it better to use ng-init instead of just the full path?

Comment: Well that is an interesting question, I just used it to improve brevity of code. But when I actually looked at correct usage of ng-init, it says that these variables are available in complete scope, so once initialized it can be used everywhere inside your code in place of `permission.headers`.
From optimization point of view, I will see it as a direct pointer to second level.