# Jquery/Angular Show/hide columns depending on value stored in local storage

Tags: jquery, angularjs

```
<div ng-controller="checkBoxController">
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <p><label><input type="checkbox" id="name" />Name</label></p>
          <p><label><input type="checkbox" id="age" />Age</label></p>
          <p><label><input type="checkbox" id="gender" />Gender</label></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="saveSelectedColumn()">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel"> 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="tableDataReset();">Reset</button>
 <table class="table-condensed" id="employeeTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="name">Name</th>
            <th class="age">Age</th>
            <th class="gender">Gender</th>
        </tr> 
    </thead>   
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
            <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.age}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.gender}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
    <a href="" title="Column Setting" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Settings</a>
</div>
        </div>



var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
 
myApp.controller('checkBoxController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.employees=[{name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'},
       {name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'}];

    $scope.saveSelectedColumn = function(){
        $scope.selectCheckBox = [];
        var $tbl = $("#employeeTable");
        var $tblhead = $("#employeeTable th");
        $("#myModal").find("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(index) {
                        //$scope.selectCheckBox = [];
                        var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
                        if(checked)
                            $scope.selectCheckBox.push(1);
                        else
                            $scope.selectCheckBox.push(0);

                        var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
                        var colToHide = $tblhead.filter("." + $(this).attr("id"));
                        var index = $(colToHide).index();
                        if(checked)
                        $tbl.find('tr :nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').show();
                        else
                            $tbl.find('tr :nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').hide();
                    });
        localStorage.setItem("localData", JSON.stringify($scope.selectCheckBox));
    }

    $scope.tableDataReset = function(){
        $scope.employees=[{name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'},
       {name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'}];

        var getLocalStorageDate = localStorage.getItem("localData");
                var testData = JSON.parse(getLocalStorageDate);
                if(testData != undefined && testData != null){
                    //alert(testData.length);

                }
    }


});
```

Have list of table data with a settings button, onclick of which an modal dialog opens. This modal dialog contains that contains checkbox equal to the number columns in the table. User selects any of the checkbox & close button, then the table is filtered depending upon the checkbox that are checked(ie. those checkboxes that are checked only that columns are visible within the table). When user presses close button of modal i am storing the state is 0 & 1 in array within localstorage(ie 1 for checked & 0 for unchecked). There is a reset button onclick of that i am filling the table back but i want to display only those columns depending upon the value stored in localstorage as 0 & 1. I am facing issue when resetting of data on click of Reset button. Please find the attached plnkr.

[Follow this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/IVQmBbvI3Fb0PXlqcoFh?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

The reason of error is probably in the **order of executing code** (show/hide columns and change employees variable). Once you changed the employees content the **ng-repeat is reload**. The fast solution for your logic is to place the showing/hiding procedure **after** the content of employee variable is changed with use of **$scope.$watch** :

```
...
var $tbl = $("#employeeTable");
var $tblhead = $("#employeeTable th");

$scope.saveSelectedColumn = function(){
...
$scope.tableDataReset = function(){
        $scope.employees=[{name:'John', age:125, gender:'boy'},
                         {name:'Jessie', age:130, gender:'girl'}];

    $scope.$watch('employees', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        var getLocalStorageDate = localStorage.getItem("localData");
        var testData = JSON.parse(getLocalStorageDate);

        if(testData != undefined && testData != null){             
            angular.forEach(testData, function(value, key){
                if(value)
                $tbl.find('tr :nth-child(' + (key + 1) + ')').show();
                else
                    $tbl.find('tr :nth-child(' + (key + 1) + ')').hide();
            });
        }
    });


}
```

**Recommendation**: I would use $scope variable for storing which column is visible/hidden and with that variable in html perform show/hide funcionality.

Comment: It works thanks a lot. Also as per recommendation given by you, can you please share how it can be done in that way as i am a beginner in angular so will really appreciate your help.

Comment: @jinishshah You should use angular ng-show/ng-hide based on condition from checkbox which column you want to show/hide for TH and TD. You can achieve working result [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327381/toggling-dynamic-table-columns-with-checkboxes-in-angular] (with this solution)